# How do you make PhoneGap IOS plugins run in a background thread

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, multithreading, cordova

In xCode 6.1, running Cordova 3.6.0 for IOS I am getting warning that plugins should be run in a background thread.

My question is how do you make the File, Camera, NetworkStatus, StatusBar, Notification and EmailComposer plugins run in a background thread?

I would appreciate some help. Below is the output I am getting in the xCode console.

```
2014-10-23 06:56:13.683 BackTracker[1689:462317] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES 

2014-10-23 06:56:13.726 BackTracker[1689:462317] Unlimited access to network resources 

2014-10-23 06:56:13.739 BackTracker[1689:462317] Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful. Your application might rejected by Apple if you store too much data. For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" You could find it at the following address https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ .

2014-10-23 06:56:14.002 BackTracker[1689:462317] [CDVTimer][file] 78.798950ms 

2014-10-23 06:56:14.137 BackTracker[1689:462317] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 133.718014ms

2014-10-23 06:56:14.147 BackTracker[1689:462317] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 9.751022ms

2014-10-23 06:56:14.148 BackTracker[1689:462317] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 224.672019ms 

2014-10-23 06:56:14.432 BackTracker[1689:462317] Resetting plugins due to page load. 

2014-10-23 06:56:16.520 BackTracker[1689:462317] Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/532EB1D5-B92A-4939-9FBD-C1EB1E8962CD/BackTracker.app/www/index.html

2014-10-23 06:56:16.709 BackTracker[1689:462317] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkStatus'] took '54.156250' ms. Plugin should use a background thread. 

2014-10-23 06:56:16.734 BackTracker[1689:462317] THREAD WARNING: ['StatusBar'] took '22.954102' ms. Plugin should use a background thread. 

2014-10-23 06:57:02.175 BackTracker[1689:462317] Application tried to represent an active popover presentation: <UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x17dd0900> 

2014-10-23 07:00:14.995 BackTracker[1689:462317] THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '10.078857' ms. Plugin should use a background thread. 

2014-10-23 07:00:15.081 BackTracker[1689:462317] THREAD WARNING: ['EmailComposer'] took '56.955078' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova has several ways to call native plugins (Native Bridge Mode) .

Try using XHR OPTIONAL PAYLOAD instead the default 
IFRAME_NAV just after deviceready event.

exec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(exec.jsToNativeModes.XHR_OPTIONAL_PAYLOAD);

More info:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/lib/ios/guides/Changing%20the%20JavaScript%20to%20Native%20Bridge%20Mode.md

Comment: I added the code as you suggested but the thread warning continue to appear in the xcode console. In fact where the app wasn't crashing it started to crash when I added the code to the device ready event.